# Intersect tool of polygons results in empty layer - QGIS

Tags: qgis, intersect

I have a shapefile with polygons and a line. They are in the same CRS and they do intersect. But when I run the intersect tool, it results in an empty layer (though there is no error message).

I have tried both the standard QGIS intersect tool, and SAGE's 'polygon-line intersection' with the same result. I have checked geometry validity.

[image]

Comment: Hi, the type of input layer geometry defines the type of output layer, so if you use the ploygons layer geometry as input, the output will be of polygon type, and intersection between polygons and lines does not output any polygon. Can you confirm if the output is empty using the lines layer as input?

Comment: If the line layer is the input, the output is NOT empty. But as you say the output is a line. Whereas I need all the polygons that the line passes through.

Comment: [Extract by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-location) using intersects as the geometric predicate.